# How to send all elements of a python list with discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, discord.py

```
list = [35, 17, 18,5, 30, 20]
embed.add_field(name="Tamanho", value="element\n", inline=False)
```

I want to be able to send all the elements that are in the list and send in the same `embed.add_field` how can I do that, I mean that the amount of elements in the list can vary, that is, it is dynamic.
How can I put all the elements in this list and send an embed?

**Edit:**

I would like to say that I want to give a line break for each element in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join it with `\n` as the delimiter

```py
lst = [35, 17, 18,5, 30, 20]
joined = '\n'.join([str(elem) for elem in lst])  # casting all elements to a string and joining

embed.add_field(name="Tamanho", value=f"element\n{joined}", inline=False)
```

Output:

[image]